# GTA V Online Heists

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was on the Humane Labs heist, and started replaying a previous heist.

After that, Lester won't call me about a new heist, and I can't replay heists anymore.

The green heist logo doesn't appear on my apartment either. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you finish the heist you were replaying?

Comment: If you finish a heist it takes a while until you can do another one. Maybe it's that?

Answer (score -1):

I have had a problem similar to this one before. Try and remove all the cables and cords connected to your console. Put them back on and then open the game and see what happens.

Comment: Down voted this answer because this is a problem with the game, not the system.

Comment: This is what rockstar suggested to me and it worked.